# Add custom filename django model (models.FileField)

Tags: python, django, django-models, model-view-controller, model

I have a model for my user and another model for music style. In my model of musical styles, I need to put the image under a name other than the original name.

The new name I would like is the 'email of the user who is saving' + '_' + 'milliseconds'.

Staying in this format:
**'test@gmail.com_1621196336'**

- **Model User:**

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, null=False)
    email = models.EmailField('E-mail', unique=True, null=False)
```

- **Model Music Styles:**

```
class MusicStyle(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, null=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=False, blank=False)
    image_link = models.FileField(upload_to='musics/thumbnail_images/##CUSTOM_NAME##')
```

***Musical style is in a different model from the user model.***

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i didnt understand what the field with milliseconde is or what is supposed to do so i replaced it with with email and music_style name, here is how you can name your images,  you can adjust it as you want

```
def upload_location(instance, filename):
    filebase, extension = filename.split('.')
    return 'musics/thumbnail_images/%s_%s.%s' % (instance.user.email,instance.name, extension)


class MusicStyle(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=False, blank=False)
    image_link = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_location)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set custom filename for your files you can do this:

```
def image_upload_to(instance, filename):
    # You can access to your model fields with instance for example: instance.name
    return f"musics/thumbnail_images/{filename}"

class MusicStyle(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, null=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=False, blank=False)
    image_link = models.FileField(upload_to=image_upload_to)
```

Comment: You should add a foreign key from user to your MusicStyle model and u can use it in your image_upload_to function like instance.user.email